What cultural significance and symbolism lie behind the ancestor figures in Osage Native American afterlife beliefs?
In the 2023 film Killers of the Flower Moon, based on the non-fiction book of the same name, there's a poignant scene that depicts the final moments of Lizzie Q, an Osage Native American, as she lies on her deathbed. The movie, set in early 1920s Oklahoma, explores the horrific murders of the Osage people after oil was discovered on their lands.
In Lizzie's last moments, the script shows her seeing her ancestors—two elders, her mother and father—as well as a shirtless Osage warrior covered in red paint on his body and face. These figures, described as a "committee," seem to be there to guide or welcome Lizzie into the afterlife.


Here's the relevant excerpt from the script:

INT. SUMMER HOUSE - WITH ANCESTORS
 
Empty except for LIZZIE’S ANCESTORS: WARRIOR, MOTHER, FATHER: the Committee that has come to take her to the heavens. Lizzie gets up and walks away with them. She glances back.

Are these ancestor figures meant to represent specific entities from Osage spiritual beliefs about the afterlife? I'm particularly curious about the warrior figure. Why is a warrior welcoming her to the afterlife? And does he hold special significance beyond just being a warrior ancestor? Is he perhaps a Charon-like figure, guiding souls to the next realm? I'd love to learn more about the cultural meanings and symbolism behind their appearance.

Notably it states that these are her ancestors. They may be no wider significance than that he's a relation of hers, like if my accountant great-grandfather turned up to escort me to heaven.

"Traditional Osage religion focused on living, not death. The Osage sought continuity through their children and family. Death was associated with night, and they had no well-developed concept of what happened after death" - https://ehrafworldcultures.yale.edu/cultures/nq22/summary

@Valorum Putting that all together would make for a good answer.
